# fixing up very old pc so it can connect to internet again

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, drivers

I upgraded my uncles windows 7 computer to windows 10 and it cant connect to internet now. looking around the internet i find the most common problem being the drivers.

when i go to device manager>Network adapters these are the network adapters he has

1. WAN Miniport (IKEv2)
2. WAN Miniport (IP)
3. WAN Miniport (IPv6)
4. WAN Miniport (L2TP)
5. WAN Miniport (Network monitor)
6. WAN Miniport (PPPOE)
7. WAN Miniport (PPTP)
8. WAN Miniport (SStp)

when i look at the properties for WAN Miniport (IPv6) the driver date is 21/06/2006 version 10.0.19041.1

I'm assuming a driver from 2006 is massively out of date. given that he cant connect to the internet i downloaded a new intel wired driver

(from here https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/18293/intel-network-adapter-driver-for-windows-10.html)

onto a flash drive on my pc and tried to install it to his. (i assumed that was the right driver since he has an intel i3 when i look at properties of my computer)

but while its installing i get this error

"No intel network connections found on this computer. No drivers were installed."

what should i do?

what other info should i provide?

Comment: "i assumed that was the right driver since he has an intel i3 when i look at properties of my computer" This is a bad assumption: very many motherboards that support intel CPUs have other chipsets for networking. For example, Realtek network chipsets are extremely common. You need to actually look and see what the vendor ID is for the hardware or consult the motherboard manual or check the network card if it is PCI

Comment: The WAN Miniport has nothing to do with the networking hardware, think of it as a software bridge.

Comment: If the PC is from 2006, it's unlikely it runs Windows 10 well at all. Not only will drivers be an issue, but the hardware may have difficulty running the myriad Services. See if your uncle is amenable to testing a Linux distro, such as Ubuntu, which does not have to be installed to test. Just make a Live Ubuntu USB, https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/, for example, and boot from USB. It should find all needed drivers automatically. If he likes it, then you could proceed to installation. Downloading files and making the USB should take about 1/2 hour.

Comment: 2006 is a dummy date - ignore it. Please add a screenshot of the entire Network adapters branch. Do you see elsewhere any devices with a yellow icon?